# Is there an irrational number which satisfies this condition?

Tags: number-theory

In fact, every irrationals $x$ can be uniquely expressed as an infinite simple continued fraction:
$$x=a_0(x)+\cfrac{1}{a_1(x)+\cfrac{1}{a_2(x)+\cfrac{1}{a_3(x)+\ddots}}},$$ 
where $a_0(x)\in\mathbb{Z}$, $a_n(x)\in\mathbb{N}$ for all $n\geq1$.

In general, for a given $N\in\mathbb{N}$, every irrationals $x$ can be uniquely expressed as an infinite $N$-continued fraction:
$$x=A_0(x)+\cfrac{N}{A_1(x)+\cfrac{N}{A_2(x)+\cfrac{N}{A_3(x)+\ddots}}},$$ 
where $A_0(x)\in\mathbb{Z}$, $A_n(x)\in\mathbb{N}$ and $A_n(x)\geq N$ for all $n\geq1$.

Is there an irrational number $x$ such that $\{a_n(x)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded but $\{A_n(x)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is not bounded for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do the convergents look like? Start with some simple sequence, like all ones